# environment variable in desktop is different from terminal?

Tags: linux, unix

I use qtcreator to build my project. When I use Terminal to open qtcreator and build the project, it works. However, when I use Desktop to Open qtcreator, [it shows that  can't not found the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb4DL.png).
Accurately, I add the libs to environment variable so that I can use it Makefile to build the project in Terminal.

So I am confused if the environment variable is different between [Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9zcp.png) and [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj3Xz.png).

The qt project file is [process.pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PORw2.png).

Comment: Have you looked at the `.desktop` file that is used to launch qtcreator from the Desktop to see how it is being launched? Have you check whether the `qtcreator` you type in the Terminal is a softlink and if so, where it points? Are the `.desktop` contents the same?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue after you log out and log in again?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I checked it. The .desktop is the same as the Terminal. I also find that when I run the program without UI, it works. However, I build the UI(for example imshow() in OpenCV), it can be complie. Now I have to use Terminal to open qtcreator.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, we found that when we run .desktop file, it does not contain bash environment. So adding **bash -i -c** in [Exec] can solve it.